# jQuery/JavaScript window.onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**Scenario :** I have html page that contains `iframes` and I have registered `window.onbeforeunload` event in html page for only html page unload event *( not for `iframe` unload event )*.

**Problem :** But `window.onbeforeunload` event is also called when `iFrame` `src` attribute is changed because `iFrame` previous page is unloaded

**Expectation :** Required to register `window.onbeforeunload` event for only main html page not for all `iframe` that exists in main html page  .

Comment: Can you show us how you're registering the `onbeforeunload`? `onbeforeunload` behaves like you describe in your _expectation_.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726171/how-to-call-window-onunload-event-for-iframe-button-click-where-parent-page-and

Comment: Clarification: do you mean that a page contained inside the iframe has a `onbeforeunload` event?